# Regular Expression for after string allowing one '/'

Tags: regex

```
String s= "folder/folder/";
```

Regular expression type is `^(s).[a-z]?/`
Conditions like:

- s file Name true
- s folder/  true
- s folder/folder/ false
- s folder/file name  false

Can you help me to create regular expression

Comment: Your post isn't clear. Can you add some valid/invalid samples for needed regex?

Comment: Oh, just use `^s[^\/]*\/?$`. You do not need any lookaheads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do your job.

```
^(?=s[^\/]*\/?$).*$
```

This positive look ahead ensures, the string starts with `s` followed by anything except `/` and optionally there can be a `/` only at the end of string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH3d2z/1)**

Comment: @Kumar  samples `folder/folder/428/ ` and 'folder/folder/filename$-#&*/

Comment: and folder/folder name/file name

Comment: @Venunadh: So you want to allow `/` in the middle of the path too? This you didn't wanted to allow earlier. I can give a regex that will allow but then your original post will be affected. I suggest you create a new post if your requirements are different than this original post. Also please add some samples for what you want to disallow.

Comment: @kumar Sorry, I forget to write true or false

`s file Name   -->true
s folder/   --> true
s(401) folder/ -->true
s(401) folder name/ -->true
s(401) file $ name & time  --> true
s folder/folder/ --> false
s folder/file name` --> false

Comment: @Venunadh: Hey, my initial regex in my answer works well for the samples you have given. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/jH3d2z/6) Last two samples are not matching exactly as you want. Please add any more samples in this demo and let me know what you want to match and what not.

Comment: Thanks, But i am not getting files from the db, will send exact files